# Recommendation for a Sasquatch Day barbecue?

Tags: wine, recommendations, pairing, cocktails, drink

Group of hunting buddies here in BC, are planning have a Sasquatch Day barbecue on October 20!

October 20 is the anniversary of the alleged [Patterson–Gimlin film](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Patterson%E2%80%93Gimlin_film) of a real [Bigfoot](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bigfoot). Hoping to start a new tradition in this neck of the woods!

> The footage was shot in 1967 in Northern California, and has since been subjected to many attempts to authenticate or debunk it.
>
> The footage was filmed alongside Bluff Creek, a tributary of the Klamath River, about 25 logging-road miles (40 km) northwest of Orleans, California, in Del Norte County on the Six Rivers National Forest. The film site is roughly 38 miles (60 km) south of Oregon and 18 miles (30 km) east of the Pacific Ocean. For decades, the exact location of the site was lost, primarily because of re-growth of foliage in the streambed after the flood of 1964. It was rediscovered in 2011. It is just south of a north-running segment of the creek informally known as "the bowling alley".
>
> [image: Patterson–Gimlin film]

With the onset of the Covid-19 pandemic, Bigfoot became a part of many North American social distancing promotion campaigns, with the creature being referred to as the **"Social Distancing Champion"** and as the subject of various internet memes related to the pandemic.

We are cooking up our own version of ***monster burgers***.

Would anyone be able to make a recommendation of what would go well with a Sasquatch Day themed drinks for our barbecue (beer and other drinks ideas are very welcome).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A beer that should be relatively easy to find across the United States (and hopefully Canada!) would be Sierra Nevada's [Bigfoot Ale](https://sierranevada.com/beer/bigfoot-barleywine-style-ale/).  Certainly on target but likely much harder to find outside of Portland, Oregon would by anything by [Sasquatch Brewing](https://sasquatchbrewery.com/).

For cocktail fans, while I don't see anything specifically Sasquatch themed, some of the recipes for cocktails involving [Monster](https://www.cocktailbuilder.com/ingredient/monster-energy-drink_434) [Energy Drink](http://www.drinksmixer.com/search/?q=monster&d=2&p=1) might fit the bill.

Comment: I like this recommendation. And yes, we can get it up here in Canada!

Comment: I going to use your [Monstermeister](https://www.cocktailbuilder.com/recipe/monstermeister) that is in your cocktail link.

Answer (score 2):

As a themed idea for wine, you could try [Mt. Monster](https://www.vivino.com/mt-monster-cabernet/w/1131269) Cabernet Sauvignon. But really, any decent Cabernet Sauvignon would pair well with the burgers.

Other (non-themed) pairings would be any decent Chianti Classico or Syrah.

Comment: The red version will definitely go well with a Monster Burger!

Answer (score 2):

How about trying [Sasquatch Stout](https://www.oldyalebrewing.com/sasquatch-stout)

> For the best experience, pair our Sasquatch Stout with:
>
> - Smoked Brisket
> - Pulled Pork Sandwich
> - French Onion Soup
> - Oysters
> - [Tiramisu](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiramisu)
>
> [image: Sasquatch Stout]

[Kokanee beer](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kokanee_beer) labels shows a **man** or ***Sasquatch*** standing on top of one of the peaks. The entity is not in the pictures on Kokanee's box packaging. He appears only on the cans or bottles themselves, and is located in one of five various spots on bottles, and in different positions on different cans. This mysterious image appears on 5 out of the 6 different marketing labels.